# How to catch a Firebase Storage error when the file doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

My react app displays an image if it exists in Firebase Storage:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/storage';

//...//

const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState(null)

//..//

firebase
  .storage()
  .ref('path_to_image')
  .getDownloadUrl()
  .then((v)=>{setImageUrl(v)}) //This sets the imageUrl state. I still get the error even if I remove this line
  .catch(()=>{setImageUrl(null)}
```

But I still get a 404 error logged in the console:

> GET http://.../v0/....appspot.com/o/userPhotos%2FJfYvcUGG8LkyNwyu1dKpJr6j4EKmE 404 (Not Found)

I tried wrapping everything in a try/catch, but the error still gets logged.

How can I catch the exception, or is there a way I could verify that the file exists before calling getDownloadUrl?

Comment: What does setImageUrl do?

Comment: It sets the state. I still get the error even if I remove that line. I'll update the code in my post

Comment: Have you tried accessing image using the URL directly in browser?

Comment: I'm certain that the errrors comes from getDownloadUrl. I still get the error even if I remove all other code except it. I cannot access the image, since it does not exist in the database, I want to only show the image if it exists. In my code, the catch line is supposed to set the imageUrl to null if it does not exist. This works, but getDownlaodUrl still shows an error in the console

Comment: Maybe .ref('path_to_image') is actually where the error is coming from?

Comment: What's weirding me out is "404 error". Why would you get a 404 error, unless you're setting NULL to the SRC property of an image?

Comment: @funkizer getDownloadUrl throws the 404 error, because the file doesn't exist in the database. This is fine, but what is weird is that I cannot seem to catch the error.

Comment: Also trying to figure this out. My understanding is that `getDownloadURL` makes that `GET` request but since it doesn't exists it logs out the error. Any luck in suppressing that?